# Change sql server 2008 r2 database name/schema and username

Tags: schema, backup, sql-server-2008-r2, restore

I have two accounts at Softsys Hosting with a domain on each account.  I need to clone the database from one domain to the other, so I can run one as a staging site and the other as the live site.

I've taken a back-up of the live database and tried to restore it to the dev account, but it fails because of database/schema/user name conflicts (both databases will be on the same server apparently so it won't let the 'same' database be created twice, which makes sense).

Softsys said that I need to take a local back-up of the database, change the name, schema name and user name, then upload that to my dev environment.  The trouble is, I just can't get it to work.  When I restore the back-up to my local system it won't let me log-in via the same username/password as on the live server - I can only seem to log is as 'sa'.

Can someone please explain to a database dunce, how I can get this .bak file from the live database running on my local machine with a working user account, and also how to change the names of the schema/user/database so that I'll be able to upload it to the dev server without any conflicts with the live domain?

I'm using MSSQL 2008 R2 and SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 Express.

Thanks all...

Comment: @closers: It is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot use the login from your Prod box on your Dev box is that the login does not exist on the Dev box.

When you move the database over, it sounds like you only have the SA login on the Dev box.

You should script out the login(s) that you use on the prod server and recreate them on your Dev box. Read up here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133

If you have the login on your dev box, or you just created it with the script above, you are going to have to connect the `Login` on the server to the `User` in the datbase.

You need to link the the new Login on the server to the User in the database. Use the `ALTER USER` statement to fix this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx

This used to be done with sp_change_users_login http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx

Comment: Thanks Raj.  That T-SQL documentation seems reeeeally complicated though, just to rename a schema and database user.  In Management Studio under the database > security > schemas there's a schema item called 'my-database'.  Is it possible to just change that schema name to 'my-database-dev'?  I've Googled this for ages and either don't understand the documentation or just can't get anything to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Dan, you just need to change the name of the database. You are allowed to have the same schema name in two databases.

Comment: You cannot rename a schema. You can create a new schema and transfer objects one at a time. `ALTER SCHEMA my-database-dev TRANSFER my-database.mytablename`

Comment: Damn, just won't work.  Tried taking a .bak file from live server, restored onto local server, changed db name and log-in name, made back-up file of this local version, but it errors when restoring this onto the dev server at softsys because of something to do with the object names conflicting with the live db there.

Comment: Hmm, tried: USE [my-database-dev];
ALTER SCHEMA [my-database-dev] TRANSFER [my-database.cmsContent]; And just get "Cannot find the object 'my-database.cmsContent', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."  Even though I'm logged in as 'sa'.

Comment: Can you post the actual error message that you get when you try restoring at Softsys

Comment: @RajMore let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1183/discussion-between-dan-and-raj-more)